# Android Gallery with first thumbnail as coverpage

Tags: android, gallery

Thanks for reading!

**Some background:**

I am building a Gallery app from the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

Only change I made to this code is to replace

`i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));`

with

`i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

to display only one gallery image at a time (Kinda like a slideshow viewer).

**Problem:**

I want the first thumbnail of the gallery to act as an Album Cover with two  `TextView`'s to display Album info.

**Experiment:** 
So, I created an `cover.xml` like this:

```
 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView android:id="@+cover/imgImage" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+cover/tvCoverText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2" android:text="Text1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+cover/tvCoverText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_below="@cover/tvCoverText1"
        android:text="Text2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the Java code. I check in `getView()` if the position is 0 (the first thumbnail) and then play around with the views.

```
package com.sagar.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.main.gallery);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                0, R.drawable.bp1, R.drawable.bp2, R.drawable.bp3 
        };

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
//            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
//                    R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
//            a.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            View view = convertView;
            if(view == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cover, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tvCoverText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.cover.tvCoverText1);
                viewHolder.tvCoverText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.cover.tvCoverText2);
                viewHolder.imgView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.cover.imgImage);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);             
            }
            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            }

            if(position == 0) {
                viewHolder.tvCoverText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.tvCoverText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.tvCoverText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.tvCoverText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //viewHolder.imgView = new ImageView(mContext);
                viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]); //Album cover is at 0th position
                viewHolder.imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                viewHolder.imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                viewHolder.imgView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvCoverText1, tvCoverText2;
        ImageView imgView;
    }
}
```

**End Result:**
When the app loads up, I first see a blank screen for a while and then the view changes to display the AlbumCover. And it's painfully slow to scroll across the images.

Hmm..obviously, I am doing something wrong. I sincerely hope someone could help me here :(

Thanks!

UPDATE: Adding `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Gallery
        android:id="@+main/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE2: So, here's some psuedo code to explain what I am trying to achieve:

```
if(position == 0)
    //show toptext and bottomtext from cover.xml
else
    //show tvTitle1 and tvTitle2 (may later include tvTitle3 and tvTitle4) from main.xml
```

Right now, only the position 0 case works and that too when I swipe to position 1 and swipe back to position 0 - the `TextView`s are grayed out and barely visible. :(

Comment: Can you post your gallery xml/creation code?

Comment: you should really be recycling your views inside `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, this probably why it's so slow. see the `getView` and other code in this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: @binnyb - Thanks for the info. I modified the getView() method and now I get a different problem. 

Problem: The first time position 0 loads, it shows the Text1 and Text2 texts correctly. When I swipe to position 1 and then swipe back to position 0 - however, text 1 and text 2 show up but grayed out. Wonder why? Should I update the code here or create a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all approaches suggested here, I wasn't able to still get a custom gallery the way I wanted it to. I kept running into `ClassCastException`. So, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670488/switch-between-gallery-and-a-linearlayout-classcastexception) what worked for me till now. This is just a workaround and incase someone comes up with a better way to design a custom gallery - do post your answer here so I can accept it.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text in your textviews everytime and not only when you inflate the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have 1 single layout file which holds the ui components in the gallery.  Right now you have 2 `TextView` components which are independent of the `Gallery`.  Instead, create some layout resource like this:
`gallery_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/picture_frame"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+main/tvTitle1" android:text="Title 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+main/tvTitle2">
    </TextView>
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+main/tvTitle2" android:text="Title 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
     </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in your `getView`:

```
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle2);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        if(position == 0) {
          holder.text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
          holder.text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return v;
```

You may find that there is some strange behavior going on when you scroll through items, so you might have to directly access each UI component rather than using the holder:

`((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);`, etc

You also may be interested in setting different types of views for `getView`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

Comment: Thanks for the info binnyb. But then what would I do in the setContentView() method of onCreate()?

Comment: @binnyb - Also, where would I define the Gallery in xml file?

Comment: the layout to use in `setContentView` would be your `main.xml` which includes your `Gallery`. You would also remove the 2 `TextView` objects from `main.xml`

Comment: @binnyb - Updated the code based on your changes but now I get an NPE on the line where it does a setVisibility() and seems like findViewById returns null. I did a project clean still this is the problem. Wonder what could be wrong. Sorry for bothering you so much.

Comment: does your `gallery_item.xml` layout contain the `TextView` and `ImageView` components?

Comment: @binnyb - Thanks - restarted eclipse and did a clean again. It found the components. But now I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams :(

Comment: From what I see online here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c85b2889aec681c9 - it's an issue related to setLayoutParams() to which MATCH_PARENT args are passed. This is so close to getting done ... phew!

Comment: I tried adjusting the parameters in setLayoutParams() by hardcoding them to various values like 150, 140, 90, etc but no use - still the ClassCastException error - any idea what could be wrong? :(

Comment: @binnyb - Could you please help me out of this :(

Comment: don't use `setLayoutParams()`.  Just don't call that. your layout params should be taken care of in the XML definition

Comment: @binnyb - By XML, do you mean layout_width and layout_height ? I couldn't find anything equivalent to setLayoutParams() elsewhere. Please help!

Comment: yes, you don't need to use setLayoutParams() in this case i believe. set the layout_width and layout_height in XML for the gallery

Comment: @binnyb - Yes, I've already set those two to fill_parent but still no luck :(