# Switch between Gallery and a LinearLayout - ClassCastException

Tags: android, view, gallery

Thanks for reading!

I am building a custom Gallery app where the first thumbnail is an album cover displaying album details.  Here's the flow:

```
getView() {
//inflate cover.xml which includes two textviews and an imageview.
    if(position == 0)
         //set some album-specific text
    else 
         //set image-specific text
}
```

Here's the actual getView() code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //TODO: Recycle view
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cover, null);
            TextView tvTxt1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.cover.tvCoverText1);
            TextView tvTxt2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.cover.tvCoverText2);
            //ImageView imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.cover.imgImage);

            if(position == 0) {
                tvTxt1.setText("AlbumText1");
                tvTxt2.setText("AlbumText2");
                return convertView;
            }
            else {
                tvTxt1.setText("ImageText1"); 
                tvTxt2.setText("ImageText2");
                ImageView imgView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
                imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imgView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
                return imgView;
                //return convertView;
            }
        }
```

The `cover.xml` contains an `ImageView` and two `TextView`s.

when I return `convertView` in the `else` block, I get a ClassCastException. I am certainly doing something wrong.

I have spent almost two days on this now :(

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the suggestions given by helpful people here,I still wasn't able to get across the ClassCastException.

So, as a workaround - I sort of "overlayed" the `Gallery` with other views that I wanted to enable/disable.

This is a workaround, so if someone comes up with a better answer - do post it here so I can accept it.

So here's what worked for me:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //TODO: Recycle view
            //onvertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cover, null);
            //ImageView imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.cover.imgImage);
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

            if(position == 0) {
                tvText1.setText("AlbumText1");
                tvText2.setText("AlbumText2");
                tvText3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                tvText1.setText("ImageText1"); 
                tvText2.setText("ImageText2");
                tvText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return imgView;
        }
```

Here's my layout `main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Gallery android:id="@+main/gallery" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <!-- <ImageView android:id="@+main/imgImage" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" -->
    <!-- android:adjustViewBounds="true"> -->
    <!-- </ImageView> -->
    <TextView android:id="@+main/tvText2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" android:text="Text2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@+main/tvText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Text1" android:layout_above="@main/tvText2" />
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+main/bottomBar" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="#A3A1A1">
            <TextView android:id="@+main/tvBottomText" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:text="BottomBarText"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The rest of the code in Main.java (whose `getView` method I modified) is almost verbatim from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

Thanks again for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what it looks like to me. When position == 0 you are returning convertView, which is a View. When you return "else", you are returning a ImageView. Your method is set to return a View. Try casting your ImageView to a View before returning it.

Try: return (View) imgView;

Never tried it myself though...

Comment: Hm. After looking a bit longer at this, I'm wondering if it's just not liking your ImageView. Take a look at this API demo for you to update the convertView the way you want and return the updated convertView.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: Thanks R, Actually I have tried this yesterday - in my previous post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654055/android-gallery-with-first-thumbnail-as-coverpage. That didn't work for me because even after using ViewHolder - the if you return anything other than an ImageView - it's going to give a ClassCastException - don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this imageview into your layout xml, and then retrieve it from convertview and at the end return the convert view.
This may solve the problem.
I have worked a lot on Gallery widget, if there is more problem do let me know.

Comment: Thanks Vivek - could you post a sample code so others too could understand the context? And, how do I retrieve the imageView from convertView? Should there two xmls - one containing <Gallery> and one containing the UI components I need ?